# Large DIY Dissassemblable Cat Cage?

Tags: cats, cage, habitat

In order to bring a cat to university as an emotional support animal, the school is requiring me to keep the cat in a cage while I'm not in the room. I don't think this is fair to the cat, but since I have no choice, I'm wondering:

How is the best way to make a large cat cage that I can take apart and put back together if need be? Would it make sense to get a couple of cat cages (read: the black metal wire ones) and put them together with some duct tape?

Comment: Why not just get one larger cat cage? My housemate uses two sizeable ones for her foster kitten litters, one of them a 3-tier one that's probably about 6 feet tall, that breaks down into smaller, easy-to-transport pieces, and has a set of bowls that clip onto the wires to keep them from being knocked over. (The other is close in size to a larger dog crate, with only two tiers, but still plenty of space.)